# How to inject a condition in all SQL queries using jOOQ

Tags: java, jooq

I am using jOOQ to generate my SQL queries and I was wondering if there is a way to inject a condition in all the queries that my application does.

For example, I would like to have something like `account = {accountNameHere}` in all the `SELECT` that the application does. Since I already have a a high number of different queries, I would like to do that without manually adding the condition to each statement.

Is there a way to do that easily using jOOQ ? Maybe using the [VisitListener](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.6.x/org/jooq/VisitListener.html) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a VisitListener will be the most thorough way to inject a custom predicate into all of your `SELECT` statements (including subqueries, of course). In fact, what you're looking for is sometimes referred to as "row level security" (natively supported in RDBMS like [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TDPSG/GUID-72D524FF-5A86-495A-9D12-14CB13819D42.htm#GUID-72D524FF-5A86-495A-9D12-14CB13819D42) or [SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn765131.aspx)).

The following blog post explains how to achieve this via a [`VisitListener`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/VisitListener.html):

http://blog.jooq.org/2015/06/17/implementing-client-side-row-level-security-with-jooq